# RecordInterceptor for Kafka-Streams Consumer

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I am looking at Kafka-streams for eventing. I tried adding a interceptor(for the consumer) for Kakfa-Streams.

I added a RecordInterceptor like the following :

```
  configMap.put(consumerPrefix(ConsumerConfig.INTERCEPTOR_CLASSES_CONFIG), "com.package.to.interceptor.MyCustomRecordInterceptor");
```

But I get an error during startup :

```
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Failed to construct kafka consumer
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: class com.package.to.interceptor.MyCustomRecordInterceptor
```

It works fine if I add an interceptor that implements

`org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerInterceptor`.

But I require a RecordInterceptor.

My question is, is there a way to add a RecordInterceptor implementation as a Consumer interceptor to Kafka-streams? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

> I require a RecordInterceptor

RecordInterceptor is a spring-kafka interface, not plain Kafka API

Consumers will only accept implementations of ConsumerInterceptor, thus likely why the casting failed. Your code is correct, otherwise.

Producers only accept ProducerInterceptor, and you'd use producerPrefix in the Streams config/map

Answer (score -1):

Kafa Stream uses producers and consumers internally, so you have to prefix the property.

For consumer

```
configMap.put(StreamsConfig.consumerPrefix(ConsumerConfig.INTERCEPTOR_CLASSES_CONFIG),"com.package.to.interceptor.MyCustomRecordInterceptor")
```

For producer

```
configMap.put(StreamsConfig.producerPrefix(ProducerConfig.INTERCEPTOR_CLASSES_CONFIG),"com.package.to.interceptor.MyCustomRecordProducerInterceptor")
```

Comment: The question is already using this, and didn't ask about producers